# reduce operation in spark returning dictionary instead dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a `reduce` operation, I am expecting a dataframe instead of dictionary. According to following code,it will give dictionary

```
def funReduce(a, b):
    result = {}
    # first element
    if type(a) is tuple:
        result = a[1]
    else:
        result = a
    if b is not None:
        for key in list(b[1].keys()):
            if key not in result:
                result[key] = 1
            else:
                result[key] = result[key] + 1
    return result

d = sc.parallelize([(1305670057984, {(1000001256903, 1000001120912): 1, (1000001423245, 1000001120913): 1}), (1000001256903, {(1000001256903, 1000001120912): 1})])

s = d.reduce(funReduce)
```

I have a dataframe similar to d, A tuple with Transaction id and its purchased product (A->B transcation) with count. So my goal now is to create a dataframe of product count(A->B), by combining all transaction details something similar to following:

```
{(1000001423245, 1000001120913): 1, (1000001256903, 1000001120912): 2}
```

with the above code, I am able to do it but the result is a dictionary. I need a dataframe instead, for proceeding further. because if it is converted to dictionary, no point of writing this in Spark.

Comment: it would be helpful if you shared the schema of your dataframe, input dataframe sample and expected dataframe sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a wordcount so either `reduceByKey` to get `RDD`:

```py
d.values().flatMap(lambda d: ((x, 1) for x in d.keys())).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y).collect()
# [((1000001423245, 1000001120913), 1), ((1000001256903, 1000001120912), 2)]
```

or `explode` and `agg`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

spark.createDataFrame(d).select(explode("_2")).groupBy("key").count().show(truncate=False)
# +------------------------------+-----+
# |key                           |count|
# +------------------------------+-----+
# |[1000001423245, 1000001120913]|1    |
# |[1000001256903, 1000001120912]|2    |
# +------------------------------+-----+
```

to get `DataFrame`.

Comment: instead of count you should have done sum aggregation ;)